# Can you recommend a fullscreen images viewer that can save an image with the press of a single key?

Tags: software-recommendation, fullscreen, eog

I have a workflow in which I need to examine large numbers of PNG images fullscreen. When I see an image of interest I need to save that PNG image to another directory. Right now I am using Eye of GNOME, but the number of interactions I need to make with the program for my workflow is irritating.

In Eog, I open an image fullscreen and then move to the next using the arrow keys. If I need to save an image, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then have to set Eog back to being fullscreen (<kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>) because the saving action changes it to be windowed. Instead of the 8 keystrokes used for this currently, I want a single keystroke to do these things.

I've tried editing the `~/.config/eog/accels` file but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there an image viewer/saver that can do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geeqie will do this in 2 keystrokes. Rather than save, use copy, same result I believe. After you are in full screen mode, press "ctrl c".  The first time you do this you will have to select the folder to copy to, after the first copy the folder you selected will be the default.  So all you would have to do is press "ctrl c"  then "enter" and continue.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion; I gave Geeqie a shot. I think that the only difference is using `Ctrl` `c` to save instead of `Ctrl` `Shift` `s` because the saving action causes Geeqie to be windowed, requiring it to be reset to fullscreen after saving (`Fn` `F11` `Fn` `F11`). It's brought it down from 8 keystrokes to 7 keystrokes, which is an improvement of 12.5 % tho, so thanks. :)

Comment: Interesting that Geeqie doesn't get windowed on my machine.  Do you have multiple monitors? If yes try locating Geeqie to your primary monitor. Also you can change the key assignment for the copy function to whatever you want in the preferences.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology isn't the clearest. If I set the image viewer to fullscreen (F11), I see only the image displayed onscreen. I don't see window decorations, or the Unity launcher, or any other elements of the desktop environment. The moment I go to save the image and a save dialog window appears, I see the Unity launcher intrude on the image viewer and I see other elements of the desktop environment. Getting rid of these things necessitates switching the image viewer to windowed-mode and then back to fullscreen mode.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the key reassignments as you suggested. With the fullscreen and copy commands reduced to single keypresses, the total keypresses required for the interaction are reduced now to just 4 keypresses (copy, Enter, fullscreen, fullscreen). That's a 50 % improvement; thanks again.

Comment: These things do not occur on my machine.  In the Unity system settings under the Appearances setting do you autohide the taskbar?  In the preferences for Geeqie do you zoom the image to fit the window?  Do you have multiple monitors?